# Src for the images does not set properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs that has a class named class='tweetCon'
each containing 1 image and I want to check if the image source exist or not so if it is available I dont do anything but if not I will change the image source with an appropriate image my code is as follow:

```
$('.tweetimgcon').children('img').each(function () {
    imageExists($(this).attr("src"), function (exists) {
        if (exists == true) {
        } else {
            $(this).attr("src", "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174758/v65oai7fxn47qv9nectx.png");
        }
    }, function () {
    });
});
```

and also imageExists() is as follow:

```
function imageExists(url, callback,callback2) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { callback(true);callback2(); };
    img.onerror = function() { callback(false);callback2(); };
    img.src = url;
}
```

now the problem is that the src for the images that are not available does not set properly though when I check the src of those images by console.log it shows that they are properly set but it is not shown and when I use inspect element of chrome I can see that src is not set . Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just re-initialize `var $this = $(this).attr("src")` and do `$(this).attr("src",...`

Comment: It is preferable to use `src` property instead of the attribute. `$(this).prop("src")`

Comment: Thank you @karthikr I changed it to this but still not working:  var th = $(this).attr("src");
         $(th).attr("src","https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174758/v65oai7fxn47qv9nectx.png");

Comment: @Oriol thank you I did what you said but still the same problem:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is `$(this)` doesn't point to your object, because you call `$(this)` inside your `imgExists` callback function but **NOT** the jQuery callback function `each`, so the `this` object doesn't point to your original `img` tag!

The solution should be save the object reference first, try the below:

```
$('.tweetimgcon').children('img').each(function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    imageExists($(this).attr("src"), function (exists) {
        if (exists == true) {
        } else {
            _this.attr("src", "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174758/v65oai7fxn47qv9nectx.png");
        }
    }, function () {
    });
});
```

Comment: @Hamed Minaee Thank you. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Just for a little tip for a better callback function use call.

```
function imageExists(url, cb, ecb) {
var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { cb.call(img,true,url); };
    img.onerror = function() { ecb.call(img,false,url); };
    img.src = url;
}
```

I added `img` as the first argument and that will then be your `this` keyword instead of window.

[**Testing Bin**](http://jsbin.com/vijosuza/1/edit)